# Functional derivative normalization sensitive to normalization of test function?

Tags: physics, functional-equations, quantum-field-theory, functional-calculus

Background: I am a physicist with decent background in mathematics.

Reading the article on functional derivatives on wikipedia gives:

> *The functional derivative $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)}$ of a functional $F[\rho]$ is defined by 
>   $$\int{ \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)} \phi (x)dx}=\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{F[\rho+\epsilon\phi]-F[\rho]}{\epsilon}$$
>   where $\phi$ is an arbitrary function.*

Note that the equation above is analogous to equating two equivalent definitions of the directional derivative, for functions of $N$ variables.

Here is my question: The equation is supposed to hold for all functions $\phi$ and yield the same derivative $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)}$. But replacing $\phi(x) \to 2\phi(x)$ doubles the LHS but not the RHS of the equation, so the equation can't hold for all $\phi$.

I posit that wikipedia isn't totally correct, and that it should only hold for normalized functions $\phi$, as in the definition of directional derivatives. Is this the case?

Providing a reference would be very useful (the wiki source didn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you scaled the right hand side improperly.

If you take $f(x)=2\phi(x)$,
$$2\int{ \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)} \phi (x)dx}=\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{F[\rho+\epsilon 2 \phi]-F[\rho]}{\epsilon},$$
you trivially see that 
$$\int{ \frac{\delta F}{\delta \rho(x)} \phi (x)dx}=\lim_{\epsilon \to0}\frac{F[\rho+\epsilon 2 \phi]-F[\rho]}{2\epsilon},$$
which amounts to the original expression in the limit.

As you soundly observed, this is analogous to the directional derivative of a scalar function of vectors, and scales the same way. In fact, all functional derivative manipulations draw their intuition from your vector analog.

Comment: Whoops, very good point. Cosmas Zachos to the rescue again :) Thanks.